# Regex matching @"*"

Tags: jquery, regex

I am attempting to use regexes in jQuery, and I am running into some problems. This is the string that I am operating on:

```
NSLog(@"It works!");
```

I want the regex to select everything between the @" and the ", inclusive. This regex works just fine in Reggy, but when put in my JavaScript, does not work:

```
@".*"
```

My jQuery code is as follows in this section (is single-quotes the issue, perhaps?):

```
var regex='@".*"';
$(".syntaxhighlight").highlight(regex,'string');
```

I know the issue is not the highlight() function, because this works just fine:

```
$(".syntaxhighlight").highlight('nil','string');
```

So, how do I get this regex working properly?

Comment: What is `highlight`?  Are you sure it accepts a regex?

Comment: `highlight` is [this](http://pastie.org/private/0j01xmywftxvn1hyuv3yuw).

Comment: `highlight()` uses `String.indexOf()` which doesn't accept regular expression objects.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I should have looked at that before hand. Without using a different plugin, is there a way for me to still achieve my desired end result?

Comment: @AehmloLxaitn: Not without re-writing it so it uses regexes instead.  You need to use `.match` instead of `indexOf`, and you need to use the length of the matched string instead of `pat.length`, and you'd need to find the start position of the matched string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `highlight()` feature uses `String.indexOf()` internally, which doesn't support regular expression objects.

However, it can be rewritten like so:

```
$.fn.extend({
 highlight: function(pat) {
  function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
   var skip = 0;
   if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    var res;

    while (res = pat.exec(node.data)) {
     var spannode = document.createElement('span');
     spannode.className = 'highlight';
     var middlebit = node.splitText(res.index);
     var endbit = middlebit.splitText(res[0].length);
     var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
     spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
     middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
     skip = 1;
    }
   }
   else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
     i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
    }
   }
   return skip;
  }
  return this.length && pat ? this.each(function() {
   innerHighlight(this, pat);
  }) : this;
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This (with some modifications) did exactly what I was attempting to achieve. I have marked it as the answer, and I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Regex are defined in javascript in this way:

```
/Your Expression/flags
```

In your case:

```
var regex = /@".*?"/;
```

Comment: This seems as if it should work, however, it does not. It has the same outcome as before.

Comment: @AehmloLxaitn `'NSLog(@"It works!")'.match(/@".*?"/)` works as expected.

Comment: I stand corrected. This answer is technically correct, and I thank you for the response. However, it does not allow me to achieve my desired result with the setup I have.